# Problem with creating a new KeyListener inside a class

Tags: java, keylistener

I'm having serious issues with adding a keylistener to my Java program.
I would like to avoid the addKeyListener() method, so I tried the following solutions:

```
public class game implements KeyListener{
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("test");
        return;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        return;
    }
}
```

And:

```
public class game{
     KeyListener listener = new KeyListener(){
         @Override
         public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
             return;
         }

         @Override
         public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
             System.out.println("test");
             return;
         }

         @Override
         public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
             return;
         }
    }

}
```

None of them worked for me.
Do I really have to use the addKeyListener() in a graphics class? I'm trying to avoid that.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: First of all class names should start with an upper case character. All classes in the JDK do, so learn by example. *I would like to avoid the addKeyListener() method,* - you can't avoid using that method. You need to register the lister with the component, so you will always need to invoke that method. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a KeyListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) for a working example you can download and test.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a particular reason you want to avoid using *addKeyListener()*?

It's an essential part of KeyListener so you won't be able to avoid using it.

Should be relatively easy to implement though. If you're using JFrame, the following code within your constructor should work:

```
public class Game implements KeyListener{

    public Game(){
        JFrame jframe = new JFrame();
        jframe.addKeyListener(this);
    }

    //implement other KeyListener methods
}
```

This way, the Game class itself acts as the listener and can implement all of the necessary methods.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was trying to use it in a wrong way, then.

Comment: I believe so, but hopefully you'll be able to work it out with the above! Don't forget to accept the answer if it helped you 